# How can I write a piecewise function latex code in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, legend

I want write in the legend section of matplotlib a piecewise expression like this:

```tex
\[f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    x^2 & : x < 0\\
    x^3 & : x \ge 0
  \end{array}
\right.
\]
```

The problem is Matplotlib not recognize \begin \end \ and so on.
Thanks

Comment: This may be beyond the basic implementation of `mathtex`, you will have to export the work to full `LaTeX`.  Look into the `usetex` rcparam.  off the top of my head, adding `text.usetex=True` to your rcparam file should work.

Comment: It doesn't work because in Latex Mode not accept spaces, or newlines symbols, like \; or \\

Comment: @tcaswell This is indeed valid LaTeX. Between `\left` and `\right` there is an `array` environment, meaning that there is no newline between the `\left` and `\right` commands. This is not an uncommon way to typeset simple conditional functions in LaTeX.

Comment: @nordev huh, learned something.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here is the solution. It consists to load the latex mathsymbols packages. It supposes that you have installed the required latex packages in your PC. More information in [MatplotlibRC](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)

The code:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams


rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = '\usepackage{amsthm}', '\usepackage{amsmath}', '\usepackage{amssymb}',
'\usepackage{amsfonts}', '\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}', '\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, \usepackage{multicol}'
rcParams['legend.handleheight'] = 3.0
#This fixes the legend line be placed at same height that text legend


def f(x):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x < 2.0, x > 2.0], [lambda x: x ** 2.0, lambda x: 4.0])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 1000)
ax.axis([x[0], x[-1], x[0], x[-1]])
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left']
ax.spines['bottom']
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ticks = []
for i in range(int(x[0]), int(x[-1] + 1), 1):
    ticks.append(i)
ticks.remove(0)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.plot(x, f(x), 'b-', 2, 4, 'wo', markeredgecolor='b',
        markerfacecolor='w', lw=2.0)
tlegend = r'$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr} x^2 & : x<2\\ 4 & : x>2\end{array}\right\}$'
ax.legend([tlegend], loc='lower right')
ax.set_title(ur'$Función\; A\; Trozos$') # If you use accents put ur option.
ax.grid('on')
plt.show()
```

An Image:

[image: Solution]
  If somebody knows how to improve the code below it will be welcome:

```
rcParams['legend.handleheight'] = 3.0
#This fixes the legend line be placed at same height that text legend
```